# What is the name of an 80s TV Movie where a man gains self-healing and endurance powers after a crash with a vehicle containing radioactive material?

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

What is the name of an 80s TV movie where a man acquires endurance powers and quick self-healing ability after a crash with a vehicle containing radioactive material?

Comment: I closed this with the newer question as a dupe-target since it contains much more detail, but mandatory disclaimer that the answer there is mine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are referring to [*I-Man*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I-Man), a television pilot for a series that was not picked up, starring [Scott Bakula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Bakula) as the title character and [Joey Cramer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joey_Cramer) who went on to star in [*Flight of the Navigator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_of_the_Navigator).  The pilot was shown as a [Disney Sunday Movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walt_Disney_anthology_television_series#The_Disney_Sunday_Movie_.281986.E2.80.931988.29) in 1986.

In it, Scott Bakula plays a cab driver in Houston.  While driving his son, they come across a NASA van that was in a crash containing an alien gas.  The father and son run over to assist the driver of the van, and inhale the gas.  The van explodes, but they quickly find out that they both have regenerative powers.  They also have great endurance.  A government agency recruits him to work for them.

Comment: I recorded it on VHS when it was first on TV, and I've probably seen it at least 50 times.  I bet I still have that tape in a box somewhere....

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about *I-Man*? Although the vehicle contains some alien material not radioactive material.

Comment: Do have a synopsis or YouTube link or *anything* to let us know why it might be that? Something that might jar the OP's memory, for example?