# Movie from the 80s about a guy who becomes invincible

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for the title of the movie I've seen on a bad quality pirate vhs in Hungary, in 1986 or 87. It was in color, and probably recent stuff then, but not sure.

It's about a man who gets invincible. Any wound he gets heals completely in seconds.

In the beginning there is some scene with the space shuttle. Later there's a helicopter following a train. The train enters a tunnel, but doesn't exit the other end.
The helicopter descends at the tunnel entrance, and the tunnel is empty, the train has disappeared.
At the end the main character drives a truck off a high cliff, into water, but reemerges unharmed.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details.

Comment: Healing Factor is pretty common in all forms of media. You'll probably have to narrow it down a bit more than that. (TV TROPES WARNING) -
 http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HealingFactor

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I'm, hoping that the shuttle/train/truck would be better clues. I suppose the shuttle scene was the key for the invincibility of the guy.

Comment: That bit about the train disappearing in the tunnel and then the pursuing helicopter descends to look inside sounds **really familiar**.  Can't quite put my finger on it, though.  Can you remember *anything* else about this movie?

Comment: I think I've found it. It's called I-man!
Googled key words, and it took me here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58636/what-is-the-name-of-an-80s-tv-movie-where-a-man-gains-self-healing-and-endurance
Thanks all anyway!:)

Comment: In fact I always tried searching for "invincibility", but the key word here was "healing" instead.

Comment: See OP comment above confirming duplicate.