# 70's - 90's movie ending with truck going off a cliff into ocean (main actor has healing powers from the sun)

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for the name of a movie from the 70's - 90's time frame where the protagonist discovers he has amazing healing powers after surviving a bad airplane crash.

There is some antagonist who is hell-bent on some greedy financial/power lust.

The movie ends with the protagonist driving an 18-wheeler truck off a cliff and it crashes cab first into the ocean. The driver is stuck inside the cab but some how the light from the sun filters through the water and because of his miraculous healing powers is able to survive the crash. Antagonist is either brought to justice or dies in an explosion from a bomb of his own making and there is a happy ending.

It's possible this movie was a STV - Straight To Video. I think we recorded it on our Beta-Max VCR and I remember watching it over and over. Searching for terms around this story line usually either yield hits for "Superman" or "Cast Away"....neither of which are a match for the plot line and certainly not the ending with the truck driving off a cliff into the ocean.

I've often gotten this movie mixed up with Project X from 1987 and Can't Buy Me Love also from 1987, probably because they were both recorded on the same VCR tape....LOL

I've been struggling to name this movie for a few years now, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*I-Man*](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/I-Man), a failed TV pilot run on *The Disney Sunday Movie*.

> When a man is exposed to an alien gas, he acquires the ability to heal instantly and survive any injury or toxin.

The ending has the main character, played by Scott Bakula, driving a bomb in the back of a semi tractor trailer into the ocean.

Found with a search for `science fiction film sunlight healing powers truck`, which turned up [What is the name of an 80s TV Movie where a man gains self-healing and endurance powers after a crash with a vehicle containing radioactive material?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58636/what-is-the-name-of-an-80s-tv-movie-where-a-man-gains-self-healing-and-endurance).

### Promo

Comment: Thank you! YES that is the one!! :-D

Comment: Fair enough about a duplicate. Reading the other description I would never have guessed it was the same. I guess different people remember movies differently. Not surprised I suppose. Feel free to lock, delete, whatever. I am just happy to have an answer! :-D

Comment: @seth Eden It's policy with `Story-identification` questions that the same answer counts as a Duplicate even if the questions differ. Nothing gets deleted, and you still garner votes. Admitted it's not a judgment on the question or you. Sorry, I usually explain this better, but I'm at a hospital for my son's birth. :-D

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Congratulations! All the best with the new arrival. :-)

Comment: No worries. Thanks for explaining and congrads on the new life!! :-D